# R - Finding duplicates in list entries

Tags: r, list, duplicates

I am trying to figure out how to get duplicates out of list objects in R.
So my example list:

```
examplelist <- list(a = c("blue", "red", "yellow"),
                    b = c("red", "black", "green"),
                    c = c("black", "green", "brown"))
```

What I would like to get as a result:

1. duplicates: `c("red", "black", "green")`
2. vector of all entries, without double entries: `c("blue", "red", "yellow", "black", "green", "brown")`

I was not able to find a function for that other than `duplicated()` which just checks my list objects in total but not the entries itselves.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `unlist` first:

```r
unlisted <- unlist(examplelist)
unlisted[duplicated(unlisted)]
#     b1      c1      c2 
#  "red" "black" "green" 

unlisted[!duplicated(unlisted)]
#      a1       a2       a3       b2       b3       c3 
#  "blue"    "red" "yellow"  "black"  "green"  "brown"
```

If you only want the vector (without the names), use `unname`:

```r
unlisted <- unname(unlist(examplelist))
```